# Why aren't tag scores updated in real time?

Tags: discussion, tags

We all know that tag score is updated every night by a script. I think that updating tag scores seems like a relatively simple task, similar to keeping track of upvotes on answers and so on.

So why is it that while upvotes and some other profile statistics are real time, tag score calculation is through a script which runs at a specified time?

Comment: Nothing comes for free when you run a web site that delivers thousands of web pages a second, almost all of them unique and containing dynamic data that changes rapidly.  That "simple task" is most definitely not simple.

Comment: Keep in mind, it has to constantly evaluate all answers, not just new. A tag edit to an old post or a deleted answer can have more impact than a new answer. The are far too many variables to monitor to make this practical

Answer (score 5):

## Blame Caching.

And even more caching.

---

More because it's inefficient. with at least 5 million users and more than 10 million questions, it's an inefficient use of resources to update each users score, especially considering that most users are barely active to begin with. You'll probably see it within a couple hours, so I don't see much reason to be worried.

Comment: "You'll probably see it within a couple hours" - They are updated once daily.